# Explanation of an implementation of the categorical_crossentropy

Tags: tensorflow, keras

The formula for the categorical cross-entropy is the following.

[image]

What should the output of the last layer be? Should it be the probabilities of classes from a softmax layer?

What is the target?

How does the following code implement 1/N, the summation and p<sub>i,j</sub>?

```
def categorical_crossentropy(output, target, from_logits=False):
"""Categorical crossentropy between an output tensor and a target tensor.
# Arguments
    output: A tensor resulting from a softmax
        (unless `from_logits` is True, in which
        case `output` is expected to be the logits).
    target: A tensor of the same shape as `output`.
    from_logits: Boolean, whether `output` is the
        result of a softmax, or is a tensor of logits.
# Returns
    Output tensor.
"""
# Note: tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits
# expects logits, Keras expects probabilities.
if not from_logits:
    # scale preds so that the class probas of each sample sum to 1
    output /= tf.reduce_sum(output,
                            reduction_indices=len(output.get_shape()) - 1,
                            keep_dims=True)
    # manual computation of crossentropy
    epsilon = _to_tensor(_EPSILON, output.dtype.base_dtype)
    output = tf.clip_by_value(output, epsilon, 1. - epsilon)
    return - tf.reduce_sum(target * tf.log(output),
                           reduction_indices=len(output.get_shape()) - 1)
else:
    return tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=target,
                                                   logits=output)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What should the output of the last layer be? Should it be the probabilities of classes from a softmax layer?

It can be either the output of the softmax layer or the raw [logits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit) (input to the softmax layer). The output vector of the softmax layer are the probabilities of each class. If `output` is the output of softmax then set `from_logits=False`. If `output` are the logits then you want to set `from_logits=True`. You can see internally that [`tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits) is called, which computes the softmax probabilities and the cross-entropy function at the same time. Computing them together allows for some math tricks for numerical stability.

> What is the target?

The target is a one-hot vector. This means that a number `n` is represented by a vector `v` where `v[n] = 1` and `0` everywhere else. Here `n` is the class of the label. There is a function to get this encoding in TensoFlow called [`tf.one_hot`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/one_hot). For example `tf.one_hot([3],5)` would result in the vector `[0, 0, 1, 0, 0]`.

> How does the following code implement 1/N, the summation and pi,j?

The code above does not average over all the inputs (no need for the "1/N"). For example, if the input is shaped `[10, 5]` the output would be shaped `[10]`. You would have to call `tf.reduce_mean` on the result. So the equation is essentially:

[image: modified equation]

The above equation is implemented in the line

```
return - tf.reduce_sum(target * tf.log(output),
                       reduction_indices=len(output.get_shape()) - 1)
```

The "Σ" is `tf.reduce_sum`. "pi,j" is `output`, the indicator function (i.e. the bolded 1) is  the one-hot encoded `target`.

#### Side Note

You should use the [`tf.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2), because the code you provided (when setting `from_logits=False`) could result in numerical errors. The combined function takes care of all of those numerical issues.